# Save json_encode string to mysql db

Tags: mysql, json

I was save this string to DB

{"form_5_check":"N\u00e1kladov\u00e9 stredisko"}

But in mysql db is this string:

{"form_5_check":"Nu00e1kladovu00e9 stredisko"}

Pls where are "\" lost ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL treats the backslash character as an escape character. If you did something like this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO foo (json) VALUES ('" + json + "');
```

you have basically three problems:

- the single backslash you have will get interpreted as an escape character, not as content; unless the next character is a quote or another backslash, it will have escaped nothing, and silently disappear.
- if your `json` contained any single quotes, and you are lucky, you will get a syntax error, as the quote that was supposed to contain the value will be closed, and gibberish that SQL can't parse follows.
- if your `json` contained any single quotes, and you're not lucky, you're now a victim of SQL injection attack, the most infamous example being [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/)'s.

To avoid all that, make sure that your data is properly sanitised before it hits the database. This can be done in two ways:

- The manual, and error-prone way includes always remembering to escape any characters that need it any time you insert a string into a query. This differs between databases. Some databases want a backslash before quotes, while some prefer doubling the quotes and doing nothing to backslashes. Some allow both. Many languages and/or database access libraries have functions that do this in a way appropriate for the database.
- The automated, foolproof and very much preferred way is to use parametrised queries and prepared statements that do this for you in a transparent and easy-to-use way. You do not have a specific language tagged, so I can't give you the solution, but the [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) site has answers for many commonly used programming languages.